# Using launcher app and stack - loss of datagrid data

Tags: livecode

I followed the lessons on how to use a launcher stack with the main stack being seperate in order to be able to save data when you save the stack.

However, I now have the situation where my launcher does a quick check on a text file on the web server to verify the version number, and if required, downloads a new version of the main stack.

Problem is now, that all data in datagrids are then "erased" because it is a "new" stack.

So the only sensible answer is to store data in seperate files anyway because the main stack cannot  store its own data and retain it? Or am I missing something very basic here?

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are downloading a fresh new main stack from the server, and the dataGrids are empty within this, then they will be empty when it is loaded via the launcher stack.

You will need to implement some method of extracting the data from your current datagrids, storing it somewhere, downloading the new main stack and then re-inserting this data.

One way to extract the contents of your dataGrid would be something like

```
put the dgText of group "yourDatagrid" into gText
```

This would the contents of the datagrid (return and tab separated) into a variable called tText

You could then re-assign the contents of the datagrids on your new stack from this variable